# Automatically copy product information into store B when updating store A

Tags: magento-1.8, multistore

I have this setup:

```
Website                Store          View
www.domain.com         Consumer       Danish
                                      English

wholesale.domain.com   Consumer       Danish
                                      English
```

When I update product name and product description for the "English" View for "www.domain.com" I want Magento to automatically update "English" for "wholesale.domain.com".

Is that possible?

Comment: Can you please explain what you want to update? Translations, products, pages, etc

Comment: I thought the title was sufficient. Altered it to more clear I hope.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible by default.

The only way to do this would be to write an observer that does this when the product is saved. You would have to determine on what store ID the data is edited and then copy and save that to another store ID. It doesn't really sound like a stable scale able solution tho.